# How to detach a pump from a Schrader valve without losing air?

Tags: tires, wheels, pump

When I pump up any tyre with a Schrader valve I always lose a small amount of air when I disconnect the pump from the valve - there's always a couple of seconds of hissing whilst the pump is being un-screwed or un-plugged.

Is any way of ***NOT*** losing air when disconnecting the pump?

A couple of seconds of air-loss on normal sized car wheel isn't a problem but I'm trying to pump a very small tyre on a mobility scooter. A fraction of a second of air-loss whilst detaching the pump means and the tyre is half flat again!

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue with kids bike tires, they really don't have that much capacity. How much air you lose depends on the pump's design. Anything that screws onto the valve is likely to lose the most air as you can't unscrew it quickly enough. That leaves the flip type, which has two sub-types. There's the type which opens the valve when you push the lever down, which is the most common I've seen. There is also a type where it opens the valve when you flip the lever up, which I've seen only on compact bike pumps.

Of all those the type I've found loses the least air is the last one, where you open the valve by pushing the lever up and close it by pushing the lever down. I found you lose very little air with those types.